# How can I scrape a value from HTML?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping, curb

I'm trying to scrape my apps keys (I replaced them with ".....") then write them into a file to be stored, but Nokogiri can seem to pick up the value of `client_id` and `client_secret` in the HTML.

Here is the HTML I'm trying to scrape:

```
<html class=" logged-in" webdriver="true">

    <head></head>
    <body id="client_applications" class="full-width edit">

    <div id="flash-notice" style="left: 354px; display: none; bottom: 30px; opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="main-wrapper-inner">
            <h1></h1>
            <form id="edit_client_application_155914" class="edit_client_application throbberform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/you/apps/bakersdoezun756487" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
    <input id="client_application_id" type="hidden" value="155914" name="client_application[id]"></input>

<input id="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="https://soundcloud.com/you/apps/pusherqueen4348/edit" name="redirect_to"></input>

<div class="field-label-and-required form-group"></div>

<div class="form-group"></div>

<div class="form-group">

    <div class="width_1_3"></div>
    <div class="width_2_3 last">
        <input id="client_id" class="auto-select" type="text" value="....." readonly="readonly" name="client_id"></input>

</div>
<div class="width_1_3"></div>

<div class="width_2_3 last">

    <input id="client_secret" class="auto-select" type="text" value="....." readonly="readonly" name="client_secret"></input>

                </div>
                ::after
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-group"></div>
            <div class="form-buttons-big"></div>
        </form>
        ::after
    </div>
    ::after

</div>
```

Here is my Ruby code:

```
url = Curl.get("https://soundcloud.com/you/apps/#{username}/edit") 
    html = Nokogiri::HTML(url.body)


html.css("client_applications").each do |node|
  mainwrapper_html = Nokogiri::HTML(node.inner_html)

  mainwrapper_html.css("main-wrapper").each do |node|
    main_wrapper_inner_html = Nokogiri::HTML(node.inner_html)

    main_wrapper_inner_html.css("main-wrapper-inner").each do |node|
      client_app_html = Nokogiri::HTML(node.inner_html)

      client_app_html.css("edit_client_application throbberform").each do |node|
        form_html = Nokogiri::HTML(node.inner_html)

        form_html.css("form-group").each do |node|
          width_2_3_html = Nokogiri::HTML(node.inner_html)

          width_2_3_html.css("width_2_3 last").each do |node|
            client_id = node.css("client_id").value.to_s
            client_secret = node.css("client_secret").value.to_s 
            file1 = File.new("client_keys.txt","a")
            file1.puts "#{client_id},#{client_secret}"
          end
        end
      end
    end   
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome. When supplying sample HTML (or any data for that matter), strip it to the bare minimum necessary to act as an example for your question. Anything else wastes our time when helping you.

Comment: I'm never truly sure what is considered the bare minimum, but I'll do my best. :) @theTinMan

Comment: A starting point is to remove parameters to tags, embedded tags, text that are not specifically used in your code or question. Most of the HTML in your sample can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `<input>` elements have unique IDs (`client_id` and `client_secret`) you can just select them directly. No need to iterate the whole structure:

```
client_id     = html.at('#client_id')['value']
client_secret = html.at('#client_secret')['value']

File.open('client_keys.txt', 'a') { |f| 
  f.puts "#{client_id},#{client_secret}"
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be pulling the key and putting them into the file @Casper ...where do I place what you wrote inside my code?

Comment: Instead of writing `css(...).first['value']`, use `at(...)['value']`. `at` is smart enough to recognize that the selector is CSS and will return the first matching Node.

Comment: I've tried both and neither select the keys and then write them to a file... @theTinMan

Comment: @marriedjane875 Not sure what you mean, but I updated the answer with how you would write them to a file. I've tested the code on my computer and it works fine.